# ffmpeg concat video fails on Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm using [this](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) library to integrate ffmpeg to my android app.

I was able to successfully crop videos with the library but now I need to concatenate two videos that are exactly the same resolution.

The ffmpeg command I use is

```
-i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 -f MP4 out.mp4
```

I'm getting the above error when I run that command on those 2 videos

---

```
ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                       built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                       configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                       libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                       libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                       libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                       libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                       libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                       libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                       libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                       libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                     Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/CameraDemo/1.mp4':
                                                                       Metadata:
                                                                         major_brand     : mp42
                                                                         minor_version   : 0
                                                                         compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                                         creation_time   : 2016-09-02 10:17:23
                                                                         com.android.version: 7.0
                                                                       Duration: 00:00:04.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6078 kb/s
                                                                         Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m), 720x480, 6010 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
                                                                         Metadata:
                                                                           rotate          : 270
                                                                           creation_time   : 2016-09-02 10:17:23
                                                                           handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                                         Side data:
                                                                           displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
                                                                         Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
                                                                         Metadata:
                                                                           creation_time   : 2016-09-02 10:17:23
                                                                           handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                                     Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/CameraDemo/1.mp4':
                                                                       Metadata:
                                                                         major_brand     : mp42
                                                                         minor_version   : 0
                                                                         compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                                         creation_time   : 2016-09-02 10:17:23
                                                                         com.android.version: 7.0
                                                                       Duration: 00:00:04.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6078 kb/s
                                                                         Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m), 720x480, 6010 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
                                                                         Metadata:
                                                                           rotate          : 270
                                                                           creation_time   : 2016-09-02 10:17:23
                                                                           handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                                         Side data:
                                                                           displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
                                                                         Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
                                                                         Metadata:
                                                                           creation_time   : 2016-09-02 10:17:23
                                                                           handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                                     Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 4 on filter Parsed_concat_0
```

> edit 1: Fixin the n=3 to n=2 changed the error message to
>   Filter concat:out:v0 has a unconnected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `n` value is wrong. You have only two inputs.

```
-i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 -f MP4 out.mp4
```

Also, in case ffmpeg complains about mapping, use

```
-filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] out.mp4
```

Comment: I'm sorry while copying I got it wrong it's actually 2 in the command that I run before :)
I'm gonna try the mapping now and come back here

Comment: the new error message is 
Filter concat:out:v0 has a unconnected output

Comment: Try edited cmd. You may also need to escape quotes and maybe switch to single quotes in the map options. Don't know what special characters are on Android.

Comment: I guess now the command is fine with the mapping fix but I get an error saying
out.mp4: Read-only file system
Do you have any idea about this too ?

Comment: That's to do with the Android OS. Sorry.

Comment: On my sistem the command doesn't work with the quotes. I marked this answer as the solution can you remove the quotation marks ? So that the answer is the same as my working command